# Debugging COMException

Tags: com, activex, comexception

I am using an ancient Intergraph routing library to do some routing.

I could create several ActiveX and COM objects just fine but there is this one type "Location" and "LocationCtrl" that throws a COMException on creation.

Here's the relevant code

```
_sourceLocation.Streets = _streets;
_sourceLocation.VerifyAutomatic = fa_sourceLocationse;
_sourceLocation.VerifyType = VerifyTypeConstants.VerifyUsingA_sourceLocation_sourceLocation;
_sourceLocation.ReplaceTextAfterParse = true;
_sourceLocation.ReplaceTextAfterVerify = true;
_sourceLocation.Map = _mapOcx;
```

The COMException was thrown upon setting the Streets property.

Here's the exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
  Message="Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))"
  Source="mscorlib"
  ErrorCode=-2147418113
  StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
       at Intergraph.LocationCtrlClass.set_Streets(Object )
       at ECNavigator.Routing.<InitializeRouting>b__0(LocationCtrl l) in C:\Users\Chakrit\Projects\NavigatorService\Experimental\Routing.cs:line 92
       at ECNavigator.Util.FrameworkExtensions.ForEach[T](IEnumerable`1 enum, Action`1 action) in C:\Users\Chakrit\Projects\NavigatorService\Experimental\Util\FrameworkExtensions.cs:line 18
       at ECNavigator.Routing.InitializeRouting() in C:\Users\Chakrit\Projects\NavigatorService\Experimental\Routing.cs:line 90
       at ECNavigator.Routing..ctor(String mapFile, LocationCtrl sourceLocation, LocationCtrl destinationLocation) in C:\Users\Chakrit\Projects\NavigatorService\Experimental\Routing.cs:line 62
       at ECNavigator.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Chakrit\Projects\NavigatorService\Experimental\Program.cs:line 23
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

The entire application is extremely simple, it contained only code that initialize some of the supporting objects, however this particular `Location` type would initialize just fine but on first invocation of property getters/setters, it would throw the above exception.

I have been debugging this for a few days already and havn't found a way to instantiate and initialize the `Location` class properly.

Any clue? Some pointers on how to further investigate this?